# MQTT Broker Setting problem for start broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

https://diyi0t.com/microcontroller-to-raspberry-pi-wifi-mqtt-communication/

I used the way that article set the broker on Raspberry but strange thing happen

According to article , I need to use

```
sudo systemctl start mosquitto
```

to start connection
then can use

```
sudo systemctl status mosquitto
```

and yes the status is active , BUT  actually can't use
if i use the command to check

```
mosquitto
```

it shows Error : Address already in use

**(Remember , my esp32 device actually fail to connection in this time)**

And if I manually close broker

```
sudo systemctl stop mosquitto
```

then check status , really in inactive

```
sudo systemctl status mosquitto
```

Now if I use command

```
mosquitto
```

the esp32 device can connect successfully now
(I have another python script using mqtt to get data)

I bet the problem is on **sudo systemctl start mosquitto & mosquitto**
permission problem but not sure how to solve
(or maybe other problem)

----20201103 update ----
log file after sudo systemctl start mosquitto and then mosquitto

```
config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
Error : Address already in use
```

So currently , the way I can connect esp32 device with raspberry by mqtt
is using command

```
mosquitto
```

But not use

```
sudo systemctl start mosquitto
```

----20201104 update ----
I'll Reply you all here, maybe I didn't explain it clear:

**Situation One**

Running `sudo systemctl start mosquitto` and then `mosquitto`

It's because `sudo systemctl start mosquitto` can't make connection work

And I use `mosquitto` to check what happen

**Situation Two**

Running `sudo systemctl stop mosquitto` and then `mosquitt`

I use `sudo systemctl stop mosquitto` to stop broker first then use `mosquitto` and the connection work

---

But it shouldn't be like this the right way is use `sudo systemctl start mosquitto` only

situation1 is totally wrong

situation2 although it can work but not the right way to do

Comment: Please check `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` for any errors (after running `sudo systemctl start mosquitto`). The path to the log is set in `mosquitto.conf` (I'm assuming you copied this from the tutorial). The error you get when running `mosquitto` is what I would expect to see if its already running.

Comment: @Brits it just show the same thing when I execute mosquitto

I'll put log in question based on charc limits

Comment: Running `sudo systemctl start mosquitto` and then `mosquitto` sounds like you are starting Mosquitto twice? The `systemctl` command should be starting Mosquitto (in the background) so running it again will result in the error you are seeing. If you want to test if mosquitto is running then use `ps` and `mosquitto_sub`/`mosquitto_pub` see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207649/address-already-in-use-error-in-mosquitto). Please show what happens in the log when you run `sudo systemctl start mosquitto` (and nothing else),

Comment: As per previous comments (and hardillb's answer) what you are seeing is expected if Mosquitto is already running (and exactly what I would expect from running `sudo systemctl start mosquitto` and then `mosquitto`) . Your real question appears to be "why cant I connect to Mosquitto when its running as a service"; and for that we would need the logs (if nothing is being logged then that is significant in itself).

Answer (score 2):

This is all working as intended.

`sudo systemctl start mosquitto` will start an instance of the broker as a background service, running `mosquitto` on the command line will try and start a second instance on the broker (in the foreground). This will fail because the background instance is already bound to port 1883 (the default MQTT port) and will report the error you are seeing.

If you want to test that the background instance is working properly then start at point 2 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716393/504554) answer to how to test a mosquitto broker.